# Modify PATH from configure.ac

Tags: autoconf

Since I need to change compiler via `AC_PROG_CC` and the compiler is not in the system `PATH` I would like to extend `PATH` variable from within `configure.ac`. Sadly I cannot find any options to do this. Or is it possible to directly change the search path for `AC_PROG_CC`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about setting `$PATH`. Try instead to set `$CC`:

```
./configure CC=/path/to/cc
```

To answer the question as written, you could set `$PATH` the same way:

```
./configure PATH="$PATH:/path/to"
```

Comment: The second is exactly what I need :) Thx.